# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_app'

Tags: python, django, apache, centos, mod-wsgi

I've deployed an app using Django 1.11 (Python/2.7.5) + Apache/2.4.6 + mod_wsgi/3.4 in a server running CentOS 7.

The page is working fine but when after login I get the following error:

```
TypeError at /
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_app'

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://server.url/
Django Version: 1.11.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_app'
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py in render, line 49
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:    
    ['/var/www/html/webINR',
    '/usr/lib64/python27.zip',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
    '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
    Server time:    Wed, 17 May 2017 12:31:10 +0000
```

The exception is in the `render` line:

```
@login_required
    def index(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html')
```

I don't think the error is caused by Apache and/or mod_wsgi (as the page is online). Any help?

Comment: clean out all the stale .*pyc files in your project. Then try again. if the problem persists post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @e4c5 done using `find . -name '*.pyc' -delete`... but nothing changed

Comment: yes, nothing has changed including our lack of a full stacktrace

Comment: @e4c5 I'm sorry! Here it is: http://codepad.org/w3yt6iPV

Comment: hm, interesting, you have no trouble with this in development?

Comment: @e4c5 (I thought that as I couldn't accept your comment as the correct answer, the best way to do it was posting the answer myself... It seems I did it wrong! would you mind create the answer to mark it as correct?)

Comment: no not at all. Don't worry about it. Please undelete your answer. On the other hand, answer reviewers thought it wasn't a proper answer. Perhaps because it was short.

Comment: I think one of the reasons that it ma not have worked the first time is because you forgot to restart apache.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a common problem.

It is most likely related to a version mismatch or old Django folders on your server.

1. Make sure you uninstall Django
2. Check to make sure there are **not** any folders of older versions of Django.
3. Reinstall Django

Edit: Probably should mention to restart server as well.

Comment: why would using an old version be a solution?

Comment: @e4c5 I guess I worded that poorly. Not what I meant.

Comment: ah, that makes things clearer. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @SierrMountainTech I thought the same but there's only one folder called `django` inside site-packages, how can I make sure there aren't any folders of older versions?

Comment: @Antonio. If you have verified there is only one folder then make sure you uninstall Django -> check to see if the folder is gone and if not delete it -> then reinstall Django. This should clear up the problem you were having. Its is the most common solution anyway to the problem you are having.

Comment: @e4c5 with some further research I have seen several post directly related to the OPs exact error and the solution for those people was downgrading to Django 1.9. There is some compatibility issues with 1.10. I am not sure if the same issues exist with 1.11. So there may in fact be a need to use an older version.

Comment: hm, maybe you are right. +1 for effort. I am still not giving up

Comment: doesn't matter, all three of us expanded our knowledge